# Copy data into another bridge table in oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to copy primary key from table Subject, Reference, Syllabus into table Reference_Subject. This doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO REFERENCE_SUBJECT (REFERENCE_ID,SYLLABUS_ID,SUBJECT_ID)
(SELECT REFERENCE_ID FROM REFERENCE
 , SELECT SYLLABUS_ID FROM SYLLABUS
 , SELECT SUBJECT_ID FROM SUBJECT);
```

The error is

> invalid table name

Comment: What relationship between the three tables does REFERENCE_SUBJECT model? Which columns link them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use select distinct otherwise you obtain repeated rows do the join form REFERENCE, SYLLABUS, SUBJECT

And you shuold join the 3 tables anyway  .. without knowing the join you can

```
INSERT INTO REFERENCE_SUBJECT (REFERENCE_ID,SYLLABUS_ID,SUBJECT_ID)
SELECT DISTINCT REFERENCE_ID  SYLLABUS_ID SUBJECT_ID 
FROM REFERENCE, SYLLABUS, SUBJECT;
```

Answer (score 0):

I really think you need to join `REFERENCE,  SYLLABUS, SUBJECT`

```
INSERT INTO REFERENCE_SUBJECT 
(REFERENCE_ID,SYLLABUS_ID,SUBJECT_ID)
SELECT REFERENCE_ID ,SYLLABUS_ID, SUBJECT_ID  
  FROM REFERENCE,  SYLLABUS, SUBJECT;
```